# Three.js shadowmap - shadow.camera is undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js

Just discovered three.js and I'm hoping to use it to display personalized product previews. Simple shadows would be nice but I can't get 'em to work ....
Whenever I recreate the examples they work fine, but i just can't get it to work with my set up.

Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/defuzed/dj23x1hj/7/)

If i comment out the `renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;` part ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/defuzed/dj23x1hj/8/)) - the scene renders as i would like it.

Debugging with Firefox shows that the `shadow` property of `light`is undefined but when i console.dir the light (replace 8 with a 9 in the fiddle url to see) that's supposed to make a shadowcamera i can see that the directional light has a shadow property.

Would truly, truly appreciate any help. I know i must be missing something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ambient** Lights **dont** cast shadows in `Three.js`:

<del>ambLight.castShadow = true;</del>

That fixes: `TypeError: shadow is undefined`

You still wont see a shadow cast because the shadowCamera frustum of your `DirectionalLight` doesnt hit the floor.

Fixed:
http://jsfiddle.net/dj23x1hj/14/